# Funnel through dimension in Google Analytics?

Tags: events, google-analytics, dimensions

Is there a way in GA to detect something like a funnel but through a custom dimension rather than a session?

I need to identify if two events were (not)appearing in a given order: 
- identify `dimensions` *project* where `event` *deleted* was not followed by `event` *created* at any time in future (date interval).

It need not to happen within one session, but I want to know if that happened within some custom dimensions.

Is that possible in GA? How?

Comment: You can filter users with two subsquent events by creating a user scoped segment of the type "sequence" (where you can specify the order in which the events need to happen). That will limit the reports to those users that have both events in order (it will not display a funnel, though).

Comment: These need not to be the same users. We have a multi-tenant setup so one user can hit the create event and the another one can hit the delete event. So I really need to identify it on the custom dimension (project) level.